# The subscription name was not found deploying to azure from teamcity

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, teamcity

When I run the commands to select a subscription manually from the azure powershell command prompt. I don't get any errors, but when I automate the powershell script from teamcity, it says "The subscription name Test was not found"

These are the commands:

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "subscriptionName" -CurrentStorageAccount "storageAccount"

Select-AzureSubscription $subscriptionName

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your subscription installed on TeamCity agent? Can you execute these commands successfully from the powershell on the machine with TeamCity agent?

In general, you have to install Azure cmdlets and add a subscription manually on the agents that are compatible with your build configuration and make sure that the user, that runs the agents has enough permissions to access Azure stuff

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve this problem. The problem was that I did have the subscriptions and all the permissions but for TeamCity I was using the SYSTEM account but had all the subscriptions on my user account. So changing TeamCity from a SYSTEM account to a User account solved my problem.